Why does multiple pricing work?
Adding multiple columns with negative reduced costs instead of only the one with the most negative reduced column (also called multiple pricing) is essential for solving some problems with column generation.
From my understanding, the RMP will try using the optimal column as much as possible, and then it will use the next best column, and so on until some sort of convexity constraint is tight. I assume that this means that some of these added columns will be zero when added to the RMP.
So my question is why does multiple pricing work, theoretically speaking? Is it because these multiple columns might be improving the objective of the RMP in non-parallel directions, and thus they (or a similar column) should take a non-zero value in the optimal solution? Or is the presence of multiple columns giving more information to the RMP, thus producing better duals somehow? Is it something else entirely?
PS: I've used column generation exclusively in a Dantzig-Wolfe context, so I might be missing something.

Theoretically speaking, adding more columns to the restricted master makes the solution space strictly larger, thus the optimal solution is at least as good as in the case a single column is added. This is as simple as that.
The reduced cost is an upper bound on how much the solution value of the restricted master will improve (in the 0-1 case). But it is just a bound and you never know for sure whether the solution will improve at all, as there are often degeneracy issues. Thus, by generating multiple columns you increase you chances to improve more the value of the restricted master. Generating complementary columns increases your chances that several new columns will participate in the solution of the next iteration, and improve even more the restricted master value.

Theoretically, what we add when using column generation are extreme points that might improve the solution. Knowing that any polyhedron has a finite number of extreme points, multiple pricing should converge (we'll end by covering all extreme points or by having only positive reduced costs). Whether it is better than ordinary pricing or not depends on the problem at hand.
